# JSON-LD in SDTT: "Bad escape sequence in string"

Tags: escaping, google-tag-manager, json-ld

Several of my webpages names contain the following character `&`, for example "Shipping & Deliveries", etc.

My Schema markup is injected with GTM (JSON-LD) but in SDTT I get the following error:

> Uncategorized Errors: 1 ERROR
>   JSON-LD: Bad escape sequence in string.

I have set up a variable in GTM, "CSS Selector" targeting "H1", which in the above example retrieves the page title "Features & Options".

But in SDTT, the code shows up as follow when testing through URL fetching:

> "name": "TOPIC TAG: FEATURES \x26 OPTIONS"

Any idea how to properly escape the sequence?

Comment: Did you try encodeURIComponent() ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply mrbubu, this goes beyond my current limited knowledge...not sure what to do with this information!

Answer (score 1):

It's more like a workaround than an answer, as it doesn't convert these characters, but when I had the same problem I just use replace in the custom variable i use in the JSON-LD microdata.
Do - for your case - instead of using DOM variable - create Custom JavaScript Variable:

```
function() {
   var h1 = document.querySelector('h1').innerText;
   var cleanh1 = h1.replace(/&/g, "and");
   return cleanh1;
}
```

That way your JSON-LD will work like a charm.

If there is a chance that in the H1 the innerText returns `&amp;` instead of just `&` - you can add it in the replace:

```
var cleanh1 = h1.replace(/(&amp;|&)/g, "and");
```

Hope this help.